# Ionic Geolocation not working when GPS is turned on

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

I am using geolocation in my app.
When the GPS is turned on before the user enters the app, it works.
However, when GPS on the device is off, and the user turns it on and presses a button to watch the location, it doesn't start watching.  (I did see that if you pause the app and move to a different app, and then come back, it suddenly starts watching the location.

This is my code:

```
public subscribeToLocation() {
let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition({ maximumAge: 12000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
console.log(watch);
watch.subscribe((resp) => {
  if (resp.coords != null) {
    this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
    this.long = resp.coords.longitude;
    localStorage.setItem('location', JSON.stringify({ lat: this.lat, long: this.long }));
    this.locationChanged.emit(true);
  }
});
}
```

I call `subscribeToLocation` when the app starts, and the user can trigger it again via a button.
It gets called when the user presses the button, but it doesn't start watching the position.

Comment: add location permissions...